# Value of textbox when using Google Closure AutoCompleteBasic is incomplete

Tags: autocomplete, textbox, google-closure

I use Google Closure's AutoCompleteBasic for some text boxes I have on the form. When the user fills in the text box after typing a key or two and then using arrow keys to pick one of the suggestions of the autocomplete, the value of the textbox just seems to be whatever keys the user typed in though the form renders the full text of the autocomplete word in the textbox. I use document.getElementById(id_of_textbox).value to get the value

1. Is this expected behavior of autocomplete and textbox interaction?
2. How can I get the full complete string instead of just the first few keystrokes? Or is there some other way to read the value?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the text contents should change when they press the arrow key? Normally you need to press enter/tab to "select" the completion option.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked into using AutoCompleteBasic, but here's some code that might help:

```
example.setupSearchListener = function(){
var searchbox = goog.dom.getElement('your-textbox');
var delay = new goog.async.Delay(function(){example.handleSearch();}, 500);
goog.events.listen(searchbox, goog.events.EventType.KEYUP, function(){
                       delay.start();
                   });
};
```

This will wait until the user stops typing, and then call `example.handleSearch()` to do whatever.